# Is there An excel function to duplicate the same row with incrementing only one cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am filternig some excel data and i have trouble with this case:
I have cells content like 
 1-5/x
I want to have the same row duplicated but the cell that contain 1-5/x must be
1/x 
2/x 
3/x 
4/x 
5/x

Is there a way to do it with vba ?

Comment: Is `x` literally an `x` or is that a placeholder for a number?

Comment: X is fix number that doesn't matter for example i have 1-2/8 so 1/8 2/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, mind you, I've made this with a whole heap of assumptions pertaining to your data set.

In your workbook, create a new sheet called "**Transformed**".  Now go into the VBA Editor and create a new module and paste in the following code ...

```
Public Sub TransformData()
    On Error GoTo CleanUp

    Dim rngCells As Range, objCell As Range, lngFrom As Long, lngTo As Long
    Dim i As Long, strAfter As String, shOutput As Worksheet, lngWriteRow As Long
    Dim objEndCell As Range, objCopyRange As Range

    Set rngCells = Selection
    Set shOutput = Sheets("Transformed")

    shOutput.Cells.Clear

    lngWriteRow = 1

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each objCell In rngCells
        With objCell.Worksheet
            Set objEndCell = .Cells(objCell.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
            Set objCopyRange = .Range(.Cells(objCell.Row, 2).Address, objEndCell.Address)
        End With

        If InStr(1, objCell.Text, "-") > 0 And InStr(1, objCell.Text, "/") > 0 Then
            lngFrom = Split(Split(objCell.Text, "/")(0), "-")(0)
            lngTo = Split(Split(objCell.Text, "/")(0), "-")(1)

            strAfter = Split(objCell.Text, "/")(1)

            For i = lngFrom To lngTo
                shOutput.Cells(lngWriteRow, 1) = i & "/" & strAfter
                objCopyRange.Copy shOutput.Cells(lngWriteRow, 2)

                lngWriteRow = lngWriteRow + 1
            Next
        Else
            shOutput.Cells(lngWriteRow, 1) = objCell.Text
            objCopyRange.Copy shOutput.Cells(lngWriteRow, 2)

            lngWriteRow = lngWriteRow + 1
        End If
    Next

    Worksheets("Transformed").Activate

CleanUp:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

... now select all of your cells that you want to transform the data for.

Run the macro and then check the "Transformed" sheet for the output.

[image]

I hope that does what you want.

Comment: yes that's what i want but i want to copy all the row  not only the cell
if column B and C containt data i want to have this data too duplicated so what can i add ?

Comment: Oh right, I missed that part, I’ll update the answer for you.

Comment: Error checking is lacking but it does the job.  If I had your workbook, i could make it all a little more foolproof but I'll leave that to you.  All updated anyway, good luck!!!

Comment: Exactly what i want , Thank you !!